# Quickly turn on / off lock screen?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, app-widgets, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z1

Is there someway to quickly turn on / off the lock screen without delving into the settings?

Most of the time I want the lock screen, but when using the device to play music / the radio I'd like quick access to the full app without needing to unlock my screen each time.

Ideally when something is detected in the headphone jack I'd like the ability for the lock screen to be disabled first time the screen is unlocked, or if already unlocked when headphone jack is used simply disable the lock screen.

Or perhaps there's a widget I can add to my home screen to quickly turn on / off the lock screen manually?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning *OFF* your screen via widget is possible (and several widgets are available for that). But turning *ON* the screen cannot work that way, as to access the widget, it must already be turned on. Of course you could use a lockscreen permitting widgets (like [C Locker Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/c-locker-pro/com.ccs.lockscreen_pro)).

An alternative is using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), and defining a corresponding profile:

- **Condition:** Headphone plugged
- **Task:** Disable keyguard

This is the most convenient way, as you only had to turn on/off the screen via the <kbd>power</kbd> button. And apart from that, you get yourself a powerful companion for your device – just check the [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) and [other questions using the `tasker` tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tasker) :)

Comment: Tasker looks like the way to go. Thanks for that as I was unaware of Tasker before!

Comment: You're welcome – and good choice, as *Tasker* is the answer one can give to every second question :) There's a free 7-day trial on their homepage if you want to check first. Enjoy!

Comment: From playing - seems Tasker can't disable the keyguard, only show the settings screen with keyguard options on?

Comment: Might that depend on Android version? Works fine for me (on my 2.3 & 4.0 devices; I've got that in my "nightstand" task: when placed in the docking station, it shouldn't show the lock screen but my nightstand, so it needs to "disable keyguard"). As Google/AOSP tends to remove features like this (just think of "apps no longer allowed to trigger airplane mode"), I could imagine that being the cause. You could try whether the [Secure Settings Plugin](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) helps here (as it might be device-dependent instead).